# Don't Automatically Title Case Examples in Documentation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation

In the [sidebar Outline here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/652/pipe-operators-and-others#t=201702071811535283987), aggressive Title Casing has turned the package "ggplot" into the abomination "Ggplot".

[image]

Could you turn this behavior off, trusting editors to choose good-looking titles?

Comment: The same issue with jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jquery/211/getting-started-with-jquery#t=201702071901459736158. This should be turned off, lots of title will contain the name of libraries / tools, and their casing should be respected.

Comment: Oh title case, my old nemesis... We meet again. +1, the title casing should be as it's entered in the topic's title. Not some naïeve automated title casing. (Culprit: `#side-menu ul li>a { text-transform: capitalize; }`)

Comment: Frankly, I'd mark this as a bug. `text-transform: capitalize;` isn't _proper_ title case.

Comment: Totally agree with this. The fact that the sidebar shows different casing from the rest of the page is enough to make it wrong for me.

Comment: I Agree With This. It Messes Up Things Like IOS As Well. :D

Comment: This will be fixed in the next production build. It was an unintentional CSS override. Thanks for the catch.